# Java: How can I know if my TableModel has a TableModelListener?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm quite new to Java and I've been developing a GUI with a jTable.
I've got a `jTable` from which I want to track changes, so I dinamically added  a `TableModelListener` to its `TableModel`.
However, some changes are made in the table that I don't want to keep track of, so I need to somehow switch on and off the  `TableModelListener`.

How can I know if I already have a listener in that model?

```
if (/* is there an event listener for the TableModel*/){        
    listVersions.getModel().removeTableModelListener(checkBoxListener);
    }
functionModifyingTable();
listVersions.getModel().addTableModelListener(checkBoxListener);
```

My intention is to prevent mycode from switching off a listener that doesn't even exist.

Comment: why do you need to know if there is a listener? just remove it, if it exists it will be removed, if dont, it will do nothing.

Comment: @IvanPeralesM. that's right and actually led me to my final code... yet I am still courious about how to know if there's a listener implemented. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast table model to `AbstractTableModel` and use `getTableModelListeners()`.

```
((AbstractTableModel) listVersions.getModel()).getTableModelListeners();
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally did as [Ivan Perales M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4421445/ivan-perales-m) suggested in the comments: I can just remove the listener and if there's no listener, nothing will happen.